# Installed gitlab-ci but only nginx welcome page shows

Tags: networking, web-server, gitlab, continuous-integration

I installed gitlab-ci using this [guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) and everything has gone pretty well.  I got to the end of the tutorial and when I go to the ip address of the server I only get a Welcome to nginx! screen. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 server, and I have seen a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694006/installed-gitlab-but-only-nginx-welcome-page-shows) answered, on stack overflow, but the answer doesn't apply to me (or I don't fully understand it) since I'm not using localhost.  I can't use a browser on this server (to the best of my knowledge) since I'm ssh'ing to it.

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab_ci

```
# GITLAB CI
# Maintainer: @randx
# App Version: 2.0

upstream gitlab_ci {
  server unix:/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/tmp/sockets/gitlab-ci.socket;
}

server {
  listen 192.168.1.151:80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80;
  server_name git-ci 192.168.1.25;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  root /home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/public;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_ci_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_ci_error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab_ci;
  }

  location @gitlab_ci {
proxy_read_timeout 300;
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_redirect     off;

proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

proxy_pass http://gitlab_ci;
  }

  # adjust this to match the largest build log your runners might submit,
  # set to 0 to disable limit
  client_max_body_size 10m;
}
```

I think my problem is in the server_name field, but my ip address is all I have for the server.  I don't have an actual name for the server set up via DNS yet, so I'm not sure what I should put for the server_name and source.example.com for the server_name field.  I've tried a few combinations, but nothing has worked.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not planning to host additional domains on the same server, you can make this gitlab instance the default virtualhost with these instructions:

1. Disable the default server by removing `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`
2. Replace `listen` and `server_name` with the following lines:

`listen 80 default_server;`

`server_name _;`

With these settings you should be able to access gitlab.

Comment: Just to add, the above for me resulted in a bad gateway error (Running gitlab_ci on CentOS not Ubuntu), and the fix for me was to change the proxy_pass line to point to 127.0.0.1:8080 which is the port that Unicorn is listening on.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me; I stopped the nginx service
`systemctl stop nginx`